Azure Dev Ops | Unit Test | Not able to connect to SQL Database
I'm trying to add my unit test project back into our pipeline run in Azure Dev Ops.
This worked in the past, but we had to remove it for X reason.
I have everything working and the first 2 test run fine. On the 3rd test it has to connect our SQL database on Azure.
Here is the error:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open server 'Server' requested by the login. Client with IP address 'IP Address' is not allowed to access the server.  To enable access, use the Azure Management Portal or run sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule for this IP address or address range.  It may take up to five minutes for this change to take effect.
  Stack Trace:

I tried to add the first IP address on the error, but then the IP address changed (as Azure services do). Well then I followed this link, which we already have checked.
What else am I missing?

What agent are you using to run the pipeline? Microsoft-hosted agents, or Self-hosted agents installed on you own local machine (or VM)?

You can use Azure CLI to add starting your pipeline. You can use command az sql server firewall-rule
You can get ip address running curl ifconfig.me
Here you have allow.ps1 script
$serverName = "<server name>"
$resourceGroupName = "<resource group name>"
$ruleName = "<rule name>"
$globalIPAddress = curl ifconfig.me

echo "Global IP Address of this site: $globalIPAddress"

az sql server firewall create --firewall-rule-name $ruleName --server-name $serverName -g $resourceGroupName --start-ip-address $globalIPAddress --end-ip-address $globalIPAddress > $null
az sql server firewall list --server-name $serverName -g $resourceGroupName -o table

And here deny.ps1 whoch you can run at the end of the pipeline to remove ip from allow list
$serverName = "<server name>"
$resourceGroupName = "<resource group name>"
$ruleName = "<rule name>"

az sql server firewall delete --firewall-rule-name $ruleName --server-name $serverName -g $resourceGroupName > $null
az sql server firewall list --server-name $serverName -g $resourceGroupName -o table


If you use Microsoft-hosted agents, or the public IP addresses of your self-hosted agents are changed often, as @KrzysztofMadej suggested, you need to get the current IP address of the agent when running the pipeline job on the agent, and then use the command "az sql server firewall-rule" to create/update a Firewall rule with the IP address.
To do so, you can following the steps below:

On Azure Portal, go to the Azure SQL server that the SQL Database connects to. On the "Networking" > "Public access" page, enable the option "Selected networks" and save the changes.


In your pipeline, use an AzureCLI@2 task to run the PowerShell script like as below. The script does the following things:

Get the IP address of current agent using the command "$ip = Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -exp ip". You also can use the command shared by @KrzysztofMadej to get the IP address.
Check if the Firewall rule "MS_Hosted_Agent" exists on the Azure SQL Server. If exists, update the rule with the IP address of current agent. If not exists, create the rule with the IP address of current agent.



variables:
  ResourceGroup: 'myResourceGroup'
  ServerName: 'briransqlserver'
  RuleName: 'MS_Hosted_Agent'
  DatabaseName: 'myDB'

steps:
- checkout: none
- task: AzureCLI@2
  displayName: 'Update Azure SQL Server Firewall Rule'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'ArmConnection'
    scriptType: 'pscore'
    scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
    inlineScript: |
      $ip = Invoke-RestMethod http://ipinfo.io/json | Select -exp ip
      Write-Host "The current IP address: $ip"
      
      $rules = az sql server firewall-rule list -g $(ResourceGroup) -s $(ServerName)
      if ($rules.length -ge 1) {
        $wantedRule = $rules | Where-Object { $_.name -eq "$(RuleName)" }
        if ($wantedRule) {
          az sql server firewall-rule update -g $(ResourceGroup) -s $(ServerName) -n '$(RuleName)' --start-ip-address $ip --end-ip-address $ip
        }
        else {
          az sql server firewall-rule create -g $(ResourceGroup) -s $(ServerName) -n '$(RuleName)' --start-ip-address $ip --end-ip-address $ip
        }
      }
      else {
        az sql server firewall-rule create -g $(ResourceGroup) -s $(ServerName) -n '$(RuleName)' --start-ip-address $ip --end-ip-address $ip
      }




I'm trying this, but the IP address could change from the agent, right? Or will the agents IP address not change, only the Azure Resource outbound IP addresses change?

Bright Ran-MSFT: I see, from Krzysztof Madej, it adds the IP address in and then removes it after it is done etc. Let me try that.

Thank you to both Bright Ran-MSFT and Krzysztof Madej for the help.
I used a combination of both of your responses and made some updates.
I did like to use the variables from Bright Ran-MSFT
Here are my final scripts:
Allow:
$serverName = "$(ServerName)"
$resourceGroupName = "$(ResourceGroup)"
$ruleName = "$(RuleName)"
$globalIPAddress = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://ifconfig.me -UseBasicParsing).Content.Trim()

echo "Global IP Address of this site: $globalIPAddress"

# Create or update the firewall rule
az sql server firewall-rule create --name $ruleName --server $serverName -g $resourceGroupName --start-ip-address $globalIPAddress --end-ip-address $globalIPAddress | Out-Null

# List the firewall rules
az sql server firewall-rule list --server $serverName -g $resourceGroupName -o table


Deny:
$serverName = "$(ServerName)"
$resourceGroupName = "$(ResourceGroup)"
$ruleName = "$(RuleName)"

# Deleting the firewall rule
az sql server firewall-rule delete --name $ruleName --server $serverName -g $resourceGroupName

# List the firewall rules to confirm deletion
az sql server firewall-rule list --server $serverName -g $resourceGroupName -o table

